# How to fix my pod install problem with unimodules?

Tags: ios, react-native

My pod install won't install the pods , i have the same error everytime :

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>.

## from /Users/bonnieandcloud/Documents/BonnieAndCloud/seducia-app/ios/Podfile:20

## -------------------------------------------

> use_unimodules!

## end

## -------------------------------------------

Also my pod. :

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

platform :ios, '13.0'

$FirebaseSDKVersion = '7.7.0'

target 'Instadating' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'ReactNativeART', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/art',



  use_unimodules!
end
```

Comment: Remove the line ‘use_unimodules!’ Completely and type it manually, remove everything around that block. You probably copied a bad character when copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention on the comment:

> Remove the line ‘use_unimodules!’ Completely and type it manually,
> remove everything around that block. You probably copied a bad
> character when copy pasting.

Pay attention when copy pasting, sometimes websites have hidden characters that could be icons from the code styler which you don't see.